# Interpolating values by group in a dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a pandas dataframe with a series of price values for different types of fruit over a series of unevenly spaced dates.  What I would like to do is interpolate prices for the fruit over a consistent time frame for each fruit type.

The hard part is that currently, some of the times overlap, and others don't (see example below).  I'd rather not extend the interpolation too far beyond the date ranges provided, as that would leave too much room for error. So I'm ok not comparing the prices of fruits 01 and 02 below, but 01 and 03 should have a window I can use to compare. The goal is to have consistent/ overlapping date ranges that I can compare changes in fruit prices, ie I should be able to compare interpolated price for fruit 01 and fruit 03 on something like 9/21/14, 9/28/14, 10/5/14 etc.

As for the interpolation, what should I be considering as I think about what type of interpolation to use?  I think that a weekly price interpolation would be sufficient.

```
id    date        price
01    2014-09-21  3.41
01    2014-11-05  5.63
01    2015-02-22  6.22
02    2013-04-11  245.22
02    2013-05-20  250.05
03    2014-08-28  10.53
03    2014-10-01  12.43
```

Let me know if I can provide any more information.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Alexander my expected result is a dataframe with the same format, that still has all of the original values, but now also has the newly interpolated weekly price estimates included.

Comment: Your question is too vague and you don't provide specifics of what is the expected result.  For example, "I'd rather not extend the interpolation too far beyond the date ranges provided".  What does that actually mean? And "I'm ok not comparing the prices of fruits 01 and 02 below, but 01 and 03 should have a window I can use to compare"  How do you determine what is acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is along the lines of what you are trying to accomplish, but it is difficult to be more precise without clearly worded goals.

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, values='price', columns='id', index='date')

>>> pt
id             1       2      3
date                           
2013-04-11   NaN  245.22    NaN
2013-05-20   NaN  250.05    NaN
2014-08-28   NaN     NaN  10.53
2014-09-21  3.41     NaN    NaN
2014-10-01   NaN     NaN  12.43
2014-11-05  5.63     NaN    NaN
2015-02-22  6.22     NaN    NaN

df2 = (pt
       .set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pt.index))
       .resample('W')
       .apply(lambda series: series.interpolate()))

for col in df2:
    end_date = pt[col].last_valid_index()
    df2.loc[df2.index > end_date, col] = np.nan

>>> df2
id                 1        2      3
2013-04-14       NaN  245.220    NaN
2013-04-21       NaN  246.025    NaN
2013-04-28       NaN  246.830    NaN
2013-05-05       NaN  247.635    NaN
2013-05-12       NaN  248.440    NaN
2013-05-19       NaN  249.245    NaN
2013-05-26       NaN      NaN    NaN
2013-06-02       NaN      NaN    NaN
...              ...      ...    ...
2014-08-31       NaN      NaN  10.53
2014-09-07       NaN      NaN  10.91
2014-09-14       NaN      NaN  11.29
2014-09-21  3.410000      NaN  11.67
2014-09-28  3.727143      NaN  12.05
2014-10-05  4.044286      NaN    NaN
...
2015-02-15  6.180667      NaN    NaN
2015-02-22  6.220000      NaN    NaN
```

If you want to flatten this back down:

```
>>> df2.stack().reset_index()

       level_0  id           0
0  2013-04-14   2  245.220000
1  2013-04-21   2  246.025000
2  2013-04-28   2  246.830000
..         ...  ..         ...
31 2015-02-08   1    6.141333
32 2015-02-15   1    6.180667
33 2015-02-22   1    6.220000
```

Comment: this looks like it's right in line with what I'm trying to do.   Thanks for the help.  The only question I have is that rather than extend the price estimates throughout the whole range of dates in the pivot table, I would like to have the first and last dates for each fruit be the first and last dates in the original dataframe. For example, the range of dates interpolated for fruit 2 should be (2013-4-11 through 2013-5-20), while the range for fruit 1 should be (2014-9-21 through 2014-10-1).  Is this possible?

Comment: See revision above.  It is not perfect because of the daily to weekly interpolation.  For example, the value of the second fruit gets cut as the interpolation breaks the weekly period.